# Collection fetch from server, not firing change when model has been delete from server

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I am fetching a collection from the server, lets say I originally start with 30 models and in the database one of these models has some of attributes changed, when I fetch the collection the change is detected and the changes are rendered. Fine works just fine.
But when the model is delete in the database and the collection which had 30 and now has 29 does not fire destroy on the missing model. The model does not exist anymore but the view is still rendered and it does not correspond to any model, because the model is not part of the collection anymore.  Need help with this one. And the view is binded to "change" and also "destroy".
I already tried all kinds of stuff, many variations in code and nothing seems to work.

Thanks

`var commentCollection = new CommentList;`

```
commentCollection.fetch({ data: $.param({ user_id:id}), success: function(){
                  Profile_view = new Profile({collection: commentCollection});
                 $("div.Profile_container").html(this.Profile_view.el);        
     } });


            function fetch_collection(commentCollection, id){
              //commentCollection.reset();
           commentCollection.fetch({update: true, data: $.param({ user_id:id})});
            console.log(commentCollection)
            }
         setInterval(function(){fetch_collection(commentCollection, id)},10000);
```

Comment: Post your code so we can see what you're trying to do to delete the `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!!!!
All I had to do was bind the remove event to the view function that removes the actual view from the DOM

`this.model.bind("remove", this.close, this)`